# Connect with SingalR client with IHubContext provided in diffrent thread

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, blazor, background-service

I am using ASP.NET Core, and I am adding some users to a collection via SingalR hub endpoint:

```
public class MatchMakingHub : Hub
{
    //....
    // called by client
    public async Task EnlistMatchMaking(int timeControlMs)
    {
        Guid currentId = Guid.Parse(this.Context.User.GetSubjectId());
        GetPlayerByIdQuery getPlayerByIdQuery = new GetPlayerByIdQuery(currentId);
        Player currentPlayer = await requestSender.Send<Player>(getPlayerByIdQuery);
        var waitingPlayer = new WaitingPlayer(currentPlayer, timeControlMs);
        this.matchMakePool.Add(waitingPlayer);
    }
}
```

`matchMakePool` being a singleton collection.

Later, I have an ASP.NET Core background service fetch the users from the collection, and notify them about being fetched:

```
public class MatchMakingBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly MatchMakePoolSingleton matchMakePoolSingleton;
    private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;
    private const int RefreshTimeMs = 1000;

    public MatchMakingBackgroundService(MatchMakePoolSingleton matchMakePoolSingleton, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        this.matchMakePoolSingleton = matchMakePoolSingleton;
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while(!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var result = matchMakePoolSingleton.RefreshMatches();
            var tasks = new List<Task>();

            foreach(var match in result)
            {
                tasks.Add(StartGameAsync(match));
            }

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            await Task.Delay(RefreshTimeMs, stoppingToken);
        }
    }

    private async Task StartGameAsync(MatchMakeResult match)
    {
        using var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope();

        var sender = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ISender>();

        var hubContext = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHubContext<MatchMakingHub>>();

        CreateNewGameCommand newGameCommand = new CreateNewGameCommand(match.WhitePlayer.Id, match.BlackPlayer.Id, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(match.TimeControlMs));
        Guid gameGuid = await sender.Send(newGameCommand);
        
        await hubContext.Clients.User(match.WhitePlayer.Id.ToString()).SendAsync("NotifyGameFound", gameGuid);
        await hubContext.Clients.User(match.BlackPlayer.Id.ToString()).SendAsync("NotifyGameFound", gameGuid);
    }
}
```

My problem is that `NotifyGameFound` is not being called in the client side. When I notified them straight from the hub itself it was received, but for some reason it doesn't when I call it through the provided `IHubContext<MatchMakingHub>`. I suspect that this is because it runs on  another thread.

Here is the client code:

```
// in blazor
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var tokenResult = await TokenProvider.RequestAccessToken();

    if(tokenResult.TryGetToken(out var token))
    {
        hubConnection
        = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/hubs/MatchMaker"), options =>
        {
            options.AccessTokenProvider = () => Task.FromResult(token.Value);
        }).Build();
        await hubConnection.StartAsync();

        hubConnection.On<Guid>("NotifyGameFound", id =>
        {
              //do stuff
        });
        await MatchMakeRequast();
    }
}

async Task MatchMakeRequast() =>
    await hubConnection.SendAsync("EnlistMatchMaking", Secs * 1000);
```

Comment: Not sure if it'll help, but why are you using ```IServiceProvider``` to create a scope? There is a ```IServiceScopeFactory``` for exactly that. Also, I don't understand why are you getting ```IHubContext``` from outside your scope. I'm not sure how well it can function without it.

Comment: You should be able to just use `IHubContext<MatchMakingHub> hubContext`  in the constructor of your injected service.

Comment: Looks like you are selecting signalrClients by their user ids from database, you sure you are providing correct user id in ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier claim or providing correct implementation of IUserIdProvider?

Answer (score 0):

I use injection to achieve this.

In my servers `Startup.cs` `ConfigureServices` mothod I have:

```
services.AddScoped<INotificationsBroker, NotificationsBroker>();
```

In your case I am assuming you are injecting `MatchMakingBackgroundService`
Something like:

```
services.AddScoped<MatchMakingBackgroundService>();
```

In my `NotificationsBroker` constructor I inject the context:

```
private readonly IHubContext<NotificationsHub> hub;

public NotificationsBroker(IHubContext<NotificationsHub> hub)
    => this.hub = hub;
```

I then inject the broker into any service I require it and the service can call the hubs methods I expose via the interface.
You don't have to go the extra step, I do this for testing, you could inject the context directly into your `MatchMakingBackgroundService`.